# Load job pending for a very long time

Tags: google-bigquery

job_CeZvrPO2l8l4m6kGBmBwBpoVqTU

Around 15 hours now - I had quite a few of these jobs complete, but three are still "stuck".

Answer (score 1):

There was a server deadlock. The problem has been found and fixed, and the server has been restarted. Your job should start progressing again soon.

Comment: Looks like this job completed successfully.